# Android spinner selected item not match with text

Tags: android, spinner

I use below code to get selectediem text and i like display something base on what been selected but weird it is not match, any clue?

```
Spinner mlogin_store;
mlogin_store = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinlogin_store);
String Text = mlogin_store.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(); 

Log.d("click",Text);  //I can see the "Abc" in LogCat. but it doesn't match the string    below. 
if (Text=="Abc"){  //first block
//Do something 
}else{
//do something else}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not compare string with **==** .
Always use string function for comparison eg.

```
if (Text.equalsIgnoreCase("Abc"))
{  
     //first block
     //Do something 
}
else
{
    //do something else}
}
```

> equalsIgnoreCase function Compares the specified string to this string ignoring
>   the case of the characters and returns true if they are equal.

Comment: ha... notice after post , im very new in java. :) Thx. anyway

Answer (score 0):

**Use Text.equals("Abc")**

Your Code now

```
Spinner mlogin_store;
    mlogin_store = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinlogin_store);
    String Text = mlogin_store.getSelectedItem().toString().trim(); 

    Log.d("click",Text);  //I can see the "Abc" in LogCat. but it doesn't match the string    below. 
    if (Text.equals("Abc")){  //first block
    //Do something 
    }else{
        //do something else
}
```